# Regex replacement in Javascript with multiple matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string:

```
var text = 'foo bar foo bar hello world';
```

I tried outputting the string:

```
<mark>foo</mark> <mark>bar</mark> <mark>foo</mark> <mark>bar</mark> hello world
```

by using regex:

```
var pattern = /(foo)|(bar)/g;
text.replace(pattern, '<mark>$1</mark>');
```

But the output became:

```
<mark>foo</mark> <mark>foo</mark> hello world
```

---

How could I specify all **matches** in the replacement parameter? What if I give multiple (e.g. 100) matches? Do I have to specify all matches (`$1` to `$100`) in the replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `/(foo)|(bar)/g;`, `bar` is in second captured group. And in replacement, only first captured group is used.

You can use a single captured group which will have both `foo` and `bar` in alteration. I'll also suggest to use `\b` word boundary to match `foo` and `bar` as complete words and not part of another word like `foobar`.

```
text.replace(/\b(foo|bar)\b/g, '<mark>$1</mark>');
```

```js
var text = 'foo bar foo bar hello world';

document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(/\b(foo|bar)\b/g, '<mark>$1</mark>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your RegEx to extend the capture groups instead:

[image]

```js
/(foo)|(bar)/g
```

Into:

[image]

```js
/(foo|bar)/g
```

Which results in:

> ```
> "<mark>foo</mark> <mark>bar</mark> <mark>foo</mark> <mark>bar</mark> hello world"
> ```

This works by making the `$1` capture both `foo` and `bar` instead of just `foo`.

However, if you couldn't do this, you would indeed have to specify all the capture groups manually